# Публикация SPA VUE.js на хостинг

Tags: vue.js, spa

Создал небольшое приложение(сайт) на vue.js. Теперь необходимо готовое приложение разместить на хостинге. Как єто сделать? если запускаю npm run build, в папке dist создается build.js и все.

```
package.json{

  "name": "superhero-app",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Eugene Kobeliaksky <ekobilske@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Мало инфы. Покажи package.json. Билд должен как-то так по дефолту выглядеть. `vue-cli-service build --mode production`.

Comment: Добавил в тело вопроса. Я просто никогда ранее не занимался развертыванием готового проекта, а сейчас возникла нужда, и я не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: А как проект создавал? Через `vue create`? Странный скрипт для билда. Попробуй сбилдить так `vue-cli-service build`.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть возможность, то переназначьте корневой каталог сайта на хостинге, где укажите путь до dist.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от хостинга

1. ответ выше, поменять путь, если есть такая возможность
2. В моем случае нельзя было поменять путь. Я папку dist (собранный проект) с помощью `npm run build`, закачивал в папку хостинга, через FTP или файловый менеджер хостинга.
   У меня было следующее разделение папок в хостинге
   папка с наименованием сайта и внутри папка *public_html*

> *example.ru -> public_html*

---

Судя по package.json у тебя собирается через webpack, в проекте может есть настройки конфигурации webpack и посмотри как куда собирается

*webpack.config.js*